# Flexslider doesn't work in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, flexslider

I'm trying to add a flexslider slideshow in a WordPress, but after including the codes in the  and the slideshow in the  nothing shows. Looking with firebug, the div I made for the slideshow is there, but flexslider just doesn't load. I'm using a child theme of the TwentyTwelve theme and I copied the header.php in the directory of the child theme to modify. These are the codes:

This is the code in the  tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<!-- Load the flexslider -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "fade",  // slide or fade
          controlsContainer: ".flex-container" // the container that holds the flexslider
    });
  });
</script>
```

And here the slideshow in the page:

```
<div id="flexslider-container">
   <div class="flexslider">
       <ul class="slides">
           <li><img src="/images/Penguins.jpg" /></li>
           <li><img src="/images/Desert.jpg" /></li>
           <li><img src="/images/Koala.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm sure you just forgot the first `<` in the copy-pasta?

Comment: Yeah I did, I have it in the header file though. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently used the FlexSlider for a project of mine. Instead of including the JavaScript and CSS directly in your theme try this:

Open up functions.php in your Wordpress theme, and paste the following:

```
// flexslider
wp_register_script( 'flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array(), '2.1', false );
wp_register_style( 'flex-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', array(), '', 'all' );
//jquery from google cdn
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.3');
```

Then below it (same file functions.php) paste this as well to call scripts:

```
wp_enqueue_style('flex-stylesheet');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider' );
```

Oh and don't forget to include the calling javascript in the template somewhere.

Comment: I've tried this and doesn't work either. For some reason my WordPress won't load flexslider. I've also tried with Nivo Slider and it doesn't load either. It seems like jQuery isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Do you have a live URL I could have a look at? Right click and Inspect Element (anywhere on the page in Google Chrome) and then see the output in 'Console'. Should display an error if it's a jQuery problem.